# Need to compare a SQL Table (Data Warehouse) against an CSV File (Local) with Transact SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table SQL Table (Sample from original):

```
CODE-SQL    DETAIL-SQL
XTAT        NULL
XTAT        SPECIFIC
XTGZ        DIFFERENT
ZAAT        ASSORT
```

And I have this CSV File in my Local Computer (Sample from original):

```
CODE-CSV    DETAIL-CSV     Y-CODE
XTAT        SPECIFIC       61450
ZAAT        ASSORT         72487
XTGZ        DIFFERENT      1205478
XTAT        NULL           78450
```

I need to Iterate through the whole table using the CSV file as a comparative file in order to assign the Y-CODE (As a 3rd Column) into the SQL Table. The iteration needs to:

Compare that IF the CODE-CSV matches CODE-SQL *And* DETAIL-CSV is CONTAINED anywhere in DETAIL-SQL THEN Assign the respective Y-CODE into the SQL Table as a new Column, ELSE Insert Missing.

This is going to be used in order to create a relationship between an inventory SQL Table and a y-Code that's going to be used in a new platform.

The result based on my example should be:

```
CODE-SQL    DETAIL-SQL    Y-CODE
XTAT        NULL          78450
XTAT        SPECIFIC      61450
XTGZ        DIFFERENT     1205478
ZAAT        ASSORT        72487
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `left join` . . . with something to handle `NULL`:

```
select t.*, csv.y_code
from thistable t left join
     csv
     on csv.code_csv = t.code_sql and
        (csv.detail_csv = t.detail_sql or
         csv.detail_csv is null and t.detail_sql is null
        );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thank you for your answer. This will help with the CONTAINED part of my comparison as well? thank you Just to confirm it should be : csv.detail_csv LIKE (%t.detail_sql%)?